# how to create sql Balance calculations

Tags: mysql

I want to create sql Balance calculations by i have 4 table such stock,stocklist,sub,sublist result out don't work.Balance error
see my code

```
SELECT cc.mm,cc.dd,cc.name,cc.q1,cc.q2,cc.staff,(select sum(q1) - sum(q2) 
    from (SELECT s1.qty AS q1,"" AS q2,i.item_id,s2.receive_date as dd,concat('A',s2.id) AS mm
             FROM  mitem i 
             JOIN mstocklist s1 ON s1.item_id=i.item_id
             JOIN mstock s2 ON s2.id=s1.stock_id
             JOIN msupplier sp ON sp.supplier_id=s2.supplier_id
             WHERE s2.receive_date BETWEEN '2016-10-01' AND '2017-09-30'
             AND i.item_id='3' UNION SELECT "" AS q1,s1.qty AS q2,i.item_id,s2.receive_date as dd,concat('B',s2.id) AS mm
             FROM mitem i 
             JOIN msublist s1 ON s1.item_id=i.item_id
             JOIN msub s2 ON s2.id=s1.sub_id
             WHERE s2.receive_date BETWEEN '2016-10-01' AND '2017-09-30'
             AND i.item_id='3') as a where a.item_id=cc.item_id and a.mm <= cc.mm) as balance FROM(SELECT i.item_id,s2.receive_date as dd,i.name,s1.qty AS q1,"" AS q2,s2.staff_receive AS staff,concat('A',s2.id) AS mm FROM mitem i 
             JOIN mstocklist s1 ON s1.item_id=i.item_id
             JOIN mstock s2 ON s2.id=s1.stock_id
             JOIN msupplier sp ON sp.supplier_id=s2.supplier_id
             WHERE s2.receive_date BETWEEN '2016-10-01' AND '2017-09-30'
             AND i.item_id='3' UNION SELECT i.item_id,s2.receive_date as dd,i.name,"" AS q1,s1.qty AS q2,s2.staff_draw AS staff,concat('B',s2.id) AS mm FROM mitem i 
             JOIN msublist s1 ON s1.item_id=i.item_id
             JOIN msub s2 ON s2.id=s1.sub_id
             WHERE s2.receive_date BETWEEN '2016-10-01' AND '2017-09-30'
             AND i.item_id='3') as cc ORDER BY dd ASC
```

Who can help me plese.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GPVa6.jpg)

Comment: Can you provide the tables defintions and some data on http://sqlfiddle.com/? Also it would help to have the exact error message or displaying what you are getting and what you are expecting.

Comment: it' don't error but Balance Invalid result value.

Comment: So please show the result versus the expected result.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GPVa6.jpg

Answer (score 0):

If i am not mistaken(your code is very hard to get trough): there is a `FROM` without select.
this one:

```
FROM (SELECT i.item_id
             , s2.receive_date AS dd
             , i.name
             , s1.qty AS q1
             , "" AS q2
             , (s1.qty*i.unitcost) AS cost
             , s2.staff_receive AS staff
             , s2.id AS mm
```

in your row 13